# Pjsip Android: How to add an Authorization header to invite

Tags: android, pjsip

Could you please help me. I'm using Pjsua2 sample application for Android. And I have question - How to add an Authorization header to invite?

```
INVITE sip:+791595XXXXX@call.com SIP/2.0
Via: SIP/2.0/UDP 95.37.XXX.XX:6000;rport;branch=z9hG4bKPjnWXRln66GYHHtnajQrPPm1ntV4PglwP6
Max-Forwards: 70
From: sip:localhost;tag=tufoJTZhvC15.yGisp-ZSzr7nTxLnfz3
To: sip:+791595XXXXX@call.com
Contact: <sip:95.37.XXX.XX:6000;ob>
Call-ID: v6TibFrvaRatCbTPe5tYjWUEsT067Nkl
CSeq: 1245 INVITE
Route: <sip:call.com;lr>
Allow: PRACK, INVITE, ACK, BYE, CANCEL, UPDATE, INFO, SUBSCRIBE, NOTIFY, REFER, MESSAGE, OPTIONS
Supported: replaces, 100rel, timer, norefersub
Session-Expires: 1800
Min-SE: 90
User-Agent: Pjsua2 Android 2.3-svn
Content-Type: application/sdp
Content-Length:   825
```

Please help me!

Comment: Did you manage how to solve it, Anton? I'm getting the same issue on the PJSUA2-API (C++)

Comment: I also need to fetch this(INVITE sip:+791595XXXXX@call.com SIP/2.0
). Please help me.

Answer (score 0):

You need to **register** first, before sending the INVITE. And in the REGISTER message you can add the Authorization header. After you are successfully register with the authorization, PJSIP will automatically send the Authorization header in the INVITE if needed.

Here is an example:

```
app = new MyApp(); 
app.init(MainActivity.this); 
accCfg = new AccountConfig(); 
accCfg.setIdUri(acc_id); 
accCfg.getRegConfig().setRegistrarUri("sip:" + domain); 
AuthCredInfo cred = new AuthCredInfo("Digest", "*", username, 0, password);
accCfg.getSipConfig().getAuthCreds().add(cred);
accCfg.getSipConfig().getProxies().add(proxy);
accCfg.getNatConfig().setIceEnabled(true);
account = app.addAcc(accCfg);
```

Comment: Some servers not send "authorization required" and decline calls without authentication